# beyond the scope of mere charity

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of "beyond the scope of mere charity" in the following passage? It is from the book “Persian Gulf Command” by Ashley Jackson, p. 241. The passage is about the miseries of people of Iran and Iraq in World War II.

Everywhere one sees people lying about in an emaciated condition. Their clothes spread out on the hedges to dry show more holes than cloth. They have not even the wherewithal to patch them. The population is fast dwindling[:] some are away harvesting in the plains, others have gone to Persia to try their luck . . . I consider their **state is quite beyond the scope of mere charity**.

Thanks a million.

Comment: The state of the poor was worse than a problem you could fix with a few coins. Are you able to look up *scope* and *charity* so we can help from there? You cannot be asking for help for the whole book.

Comment: Hi! thanks very much. I am so sorry, I had guessed this meaning, but the book is full of old or uncommon words and phrases, and because of that, I am reading it scrupulosity. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is stating that they are in such a state, that it cannot be simply fixed by giving them "mere charity" or a small donation. They would need much beyond that in order to be helped.